# Navigation Through pages using asp-action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am new to the technology of asp.net core. I have made a layout view that has the styling and the links for each page. However, these links are not working. And I have made an action method for each in the controller. My question is:

```
Where should these links that appear in the bar be?
Should I declare them on the layout page or in each page?
```

This is how I pass them in the layout page inside the shared folder inside the views folder

```
       <nav>
        <ul class="nav__links">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a asp-action="Contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a asp-action="About">About</a></li>
        </ul>
       </nav>
```

Action methods:

```
  public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Index");
    }
  public IActionResult About()
    {
        return View("About");
    }

    public ViewResult Contact()
    {

        return View("Contact");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding the @addTagHelper in ViewImports view.
For more details click the link [@addTagHelpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1#:%7E:text=%40addTagHelper%20makes%20Tag%20Helpers%20available&text=The%20%40addTagHelper%20directive%20makes%20Tag,file%20is%20Pages%2F_ViewImports.&text=The%20code%20above%20uses%20the,AspNetCore.)